# Pass dataset to a javascript validation from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, callback, dataset

I am trying to minimise postback in my web app. I have a number of
inter-dependent dropdowns, an onselectedindexchange event fires for each one
which obviously causes a postback. Is there a way I can get all my data from
a dataset\datareader into some javascript arrays and then use client side
events to handle the inter-dependent dropdowns? Any code examples?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just echo the JSON encoded data inside a `script` tag:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = <?php echo json_encode($dataSetAsPhpArray); ?>
</script>
</head>
```

`dataset` will be a JS array or object depending on what kind of PHP array `$dataSetAsPhpArray` was. Numerically indexed array results in JS array, while assoc array results in JS object.

Comment: I did get this . but can't I pass the $dataSetAsPhpArray as dataset that is returned from the sql query? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: My code basically is this - > <head>
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect(DATABASE_HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die('Error Connecting to MySQL');
mysql_select_db(DATABASE_DATABASENAME) or die('Unknown database');
$dataset_for_sets = mysql_query($query_for_survey_sets);
  

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = <?php echo json_encode($dataset_for_sets); ?> ;
alert(dataset);
</script>
</head>

Comment: You can't because `mysql_query` doesn't return an array, but a resource. You'll have to build the array yourself using mysql_fetch_row/array/object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript Object Notation. JSON is a method for other languages to pass information to javascript. PHP has a function
    encode_json( $array_of_data );
You should be able to do something like:

```
 Header( 'Content-type:json' );
 //gather data
 echo json_encode( $your_data );
```

If you are using jQuery the Javascript code would look like

```
 $.ajax({
   url: your_url,
   type: GET or POST,
   dateType: json,
   success: function(){
     //manipulate dom here
   }
 });
```